# Reset countdown based on hour set

Tags: javascript, time, timer

How can I make my timer reset more dynamically. I currently have it on a 12 hour countdown based on the real time with *new Date()*. If I wanted to make the timer reset for instance very 2 hours I need a lot more if and else if statements to do the math.

What is the proper way of looping this timer without writing 20 if statements?
Currently if the time is 00:00 to 11:59 it will countdown from 12 hours. Once it becomes 12:01 i invoke a different equation where it's 23 minus the current hour to determine the new countdown hour.

If I were to make a countdown that resets every 4 or 2 hours instead of every 12 hours I then need to create more else if statements which I would rather not do.

```
function timer() {
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours() 
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
  if (hours < 12) { 
      var hoursLeft = 11 - hours; 
      var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
      var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;

      if(minsLeft==60) {
        minsLeft=0;
        hoursLeft++;
      }

      if(secsLeft==60) {
        secsLeft=0;
        minsLeft++;
      }
  } else if (hours >= 12) {
    var hoursLeft = 23 - hours;
    var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
    var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;

    if(minsLeft==60) {
        minsLeft=0;
        hoursLeft++;
    } 

   if(secsLeft==60) {
     secsLeft=0;
     minsLeft++;
    }
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/teomhk/pen/JBNRNz)

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  I created another timer that clears the first and then restarts the original timer function.  I'm not clear if this is the exact use you were looking for but it should get you going in the right direction. If you are looking to reset to a certain time you can change that in the timerUpdate function before starting timer().

```js
function timer() {
 var currentTime = new Date()
 var hours = currentTime.getHours() 
 var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
 var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
 if (hours < 2) { 
  var hoursLeft = 1 - hours; 
  var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
   var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;

  if(minsLeft==60) {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }
    
  if(secsLeft==60) {
   secsLeft=0;
   minsLeft++;
  }
 } else if (hours >= 2) {
  var hoursLeft = 2 + 1 - hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
  var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;

  if(minsLeft==60) {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  } 
    
  if(secsLeft==60) {
   secsLeft=0;
      minsLeft++;
  }
 }
  
 document.getElementById('timerUpFront').innerHTML= "<br><strong>countdown</strong><br>"+ hoursLeft + " hours " + minsLeft + " minutes " + secsLeft + " seconds";
}


var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
var resetTimer = setInterval("timerUpdate()", 1000*60*4);

function timerUpdate(){
  clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
  timer();
}
```

Comment: The hour set is going negative https://codepen.io/teomhk/pen/ZjKVQa . I am just trying to create a simple countdown timer that resets every X amount of time. But I want to use new Date() to fetch the real date. This way if you open the window in another browser time the countdown will be the same. If I don't use the real time then the countdown will always start from the beginning on each new browser tab.

Comment: sorry but I'm not clear on what you mean by reset (i.e. what you want to reset to).  if there is a specific thing/time you want to reset to you can add it as a line in the timerUpdate function.  it is in this function that you can customize how you want it to behave.  hope this helps.